# Two divs inside centered wrapper.. So confused

Tags: html, facebook, css, css-float

**Here's my code:** http://pastebin.com/gjyKH5hD

**Live example:** http://rusti.dk/test/

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've been fiddling with this for days now. I thought it was a simple task, apparently not for me. Would really appreciate a bright mind to help me out.

Basicly all I'm trying to make is two divs next to each other centered on the page. With a 1px black border going all the way around and inbetween.

**Left box:** 350px width, 600px min-height, used to display facebook like box.

**Right box:** 450px width, 600px min-height, used for the content of the page.

**Background:** One big image.

Could anyone help me out? I think it's the FB-likebox that might be the troublemaker, but I'm really not sure. :/

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm trying to make(Made in photoshop):
http://i.stack.imgur.com/LpYBJ.jpg

Comment: Can u make a jsfiddle of your issue? That would make it extremly easy to edit and suggest solutions.

Comment: same thing can be achieved with simple display:inline-block as follows - http://jsfiddle.net/qncns/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed one closing `</div>` for the left box.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/2qj5a/

I've added it in line 12.